# Join broken paragraphs Regex Sigil

Tags: epub, html, sigil

I'm trying to edit some xhtml on Sigil.

With the command `"<p>([a-z])` I'm able to find all paragraphs that begin with lower case. That tells me that they shouldn't be separate from the previous one. It's just a conversion issue.

What should I do to delete both the < p> from that paragraph and the `</p>` from the previous one in order to join the two blocks of text into one single paragraph??

It looks something like this:

```
<p> ... that is why relationships</p>

<p> are not what they should be.
```

And it should be:

```
<p> that is why relationships are not what they should be.</p>
```

Comment: I miss Sigil. I wish it were still being developed.

Comment: Sigil *is* being developed. The latest [pre-release](https://github.com/Sigil-Ebook/Sigil/releases) has some bugs, though..

Comment: What OS are you running Sigil on? Windows?

Comment: _What OS are you running Sigil on? Windows?_

All of them. :-)

However, it doesn't really matter, because it works the same on all of them.

Answer (score 3):

The following regex should cover most cases.

Find:

```
([[:lower:]],*;*:*)</p>\s+<p[^>]*>\s*([[:lower:]])
```

Replace:

```
\1 \2
```

Answer (score 1):

Sigil's regex engine is kind of fussy; I'm not sure that the anonymous answer above would work.

I answered this [on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-join-broken-Paragraphs-from-an-ePub-using-Regex-on-Sigil/answer/David-Kudler), but I'll post the answer again here, because it seems like that would be helpful:

> Ah. Let me guess. You're converting from a PDF. You have my sympathy. :-)
>
> I've done this. Here's the search expression I used:

```
([a-z]|,|;)</p>\s+<p>
```

> That found paragraphs that ended without a period, exclamation point, question mark, or right double quotes. (Since I'm assuming you're working from a PDF of a print document, I didn't include in the query all of the other possible marks, since, for instance, a left double quotation mark is extremely unlikely to come at the end of a text line.)
>
> The replace expression was simply this:

```
\1
```

> Note that there's a space after the wildcard, so that you don't end up smooshing words together.
>
> That should get rid of the unwanted paragraph breaks and splice your text together properly.
>
> Unfortunately, if you've got letters reproduced in the book or some other text format that has paragraphs ending in commas, semicolons, or lower case letters, you'll have to do Replace/Find and go case by case rather than Replace All.

Comment: `Sigil's regex engine is kind of fussy`

Sigil uses PCRE, which is pretty much the best RE engine there is. 

`I'm not sure that the anonymous answer above would work.`

If you were referrring to my suggestion, it *does* work and unlike your suggestion will only merge broken paragraphs if the next paragraph starts with lower case character.

Comment: The code David Kudler described above on October 2, 2015 has cleaned up hundreds of whitespace problems in ebooks I have been formatting. I love it. But when I stored the code in a folder in OneNote and then pasted it to a new ebook, it stopped working. This was extremely annoying. Perhaps OneNote added some dirty html or whatever. I now store in the code in Notepad++ which has proved to be a better home. It cleans up whitespaces when pasted in from Notepad**. Thanks for contributing the code, David.

Answer (score 0):

This worked and you can play with it if you want. Please copy it before changing it. https://regex101.com/r/gO0zG0/1.

A regex replace is like this in Perl: `$s=~s/OLDPATTERN/NEWPATTERN/g;`

The regex was: `/<\/p>\n\n<p>//g;`

Replace the first part between the first two `//` with nothing. The `\n` SHOULD be properly initialized by the regex engine for your operating system (you shouldn't have to do a thing),  because it has different values for different OSes. But if that `\n` doesn't work, please let me know. You might have to try `\l\r` or `\r\l`.